# Update columns by joining more than one columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two tables and I need to update pro_sales column values in the first table from `pro_sales` values in the second.

```
df1 <- data.frame(storecode = c(100,100,100,200,200),
                  productcode = c(1,2,3,1,2), pro_sales = c(0,0,0,0,0))
df2 <- data.frame(storecode = c(100,100,200),
                  productcode = c(1,2,1), pro_sales = c(0,1,0))
```

I need to left join on the columns `storecode` and `productcode`. Below should be my final table:

```
  storecode productcode  pro_sales
1       100           1         0
2       100           2         1
3       100           3         0
4       200           1         0
5       200           2         0
```

I was able to left join in dplyr but after that i need help please?

```
df1 %>%
  left_join(df2,c("storecode"="storecode","productcode"="productcode")) %>% 
  mutate( ???? ) %>%
  select(names, match, value = value.x)
```

Thank you.

Comment: what do you want to do with the column values that are not in the second pro_sales column? Set them to zero or set them to the values in the first data frame.

Comment: The column names you use in your code example do not match the columns you have in your datasets (i.e. capital letters).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to use an update join with the `data.table`-package:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)

df1[df2, on = .(storecode, productcode), pro_sales := i.pro_sales][]
```

which gives:

> ```
>    storecode productcode pro_sales
> 1:       100           1         0
> 2:       100           2         1
> 3:       100           3         0
> 4:       200           1         0
> 5:       200           2         0
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
df1 <- data.frame(storecode=c(100,100,100,200,200),
                  productcode=c(1,2,3,1,2),pro_sales=c(0,0,0,0,0))
df2 <- data.frame(storecode=c(100,100,200),
                  productcode=c(1,2,1),pro_sales=c(0,1,0))

library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  left_join(df2, by = c("storecode","productcode")) %>% 
  mutate(pro_sales.y = coalesce(pro_sales.y, 0)) %>%
  select(storecode, productcode, pro_sales = pro_sales.y)

#   storecode productcode pro_sales
# 1       100           1         0
# 2       100           2         1
# 3       100           3         0
# 4       200           1         0
# 5       200           2         0
```

I assume that if you want to update values in first table given the second table, as you mentioned, then NA values should be zeros and not what you have in your first table.

Comment: Thank you very much for the support. Is there a way to do this in sqldf update statement?

Comment: It is mainly a join and then a column update, so I'm pretty sure there will be something equivalent. Unfortunately, I'm not using `sqldf` much. Maybe update your question asking a `sqldf` alternative? Or post a new question?